# CodeIgniter - JS pop up form opens then closes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to create a pop up form for when the user wants to upload an image. I have gotten the form to open on the page using some simple JS, but for some reason it opens and then closes right away. Im thinking its something in the way I am accessing it through the button.

button:

```
<div class="upload">
    <?php
            $data = array('onsubmit' => "login('show')"); 
            echo form_open('',$data); 
            echo form_submit('follow', 'Follow'); 
            echo form_close(); 
    ?>
</div>
```

userprofile.js:

```
function login(showhide)
{
  if(showhide == "show")
  {
      document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
  }
  else if(showhide == "hide")
  {
      document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}
```

Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: You sure your form isn't just submitting and refreshing the page? It is, after all, in the onsubmit.

Comment: Im not sure, where would that be happening? How can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you are having jQuery included then I would suggest using http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ to hide and show your element.

```
function login()
{
  jQuery('#popupbox').toggle();
}
```

**Update:**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="upload">
    <?php
            $data = array('id' => "form_holder"); 
            echo form_open('',$data); 
            echo form_submit('follow', 'Follow'); 
            echo form_close(); 
    ?>
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#form_holder" ).submit(function( event ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       jQuery('#popupbox').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: That doesnt answer my question

Comment: @Divergent, I understand that but that was tip to improve your code, and as an answer it looks like your form is being submitted when you submit your form. I will update code in above example.

Comment: I dont see how that fixes my problem? I implemented it and it didnt do anything, it actually stopped showing the form in total